# UI element jumps after move

Tags: uwp

I have an image taken from a PDF in ScrollViewer that is in Canvas. I want to put "Points of Interest" in that image and I want to move that POI / Mark with that image. So far I can put mark to the correct position and that mark moves along with the moving image. The problem is that on a first move / start of drag of image my mark jumps away AND THEN moves along with the image..

I get a position from image: `Point p = e.GetPosition(sender as Image)`.

In the image below you can see situation, when I start to drag the image after I've put that mark. I have marked down POI in left fragment / border of an image that was moved to right border of canvas.. So just left fragment / border of an image was visible

[image: annoying jump/teleport]

How can I get rid of that? I don't use OnStartManipulation / OnStartDrag event

Dimensions of canvas: 400 x 702
Dimensions of image: 1362 x 792

Movement of mark is implemented via updating Margin

Here is the code:

```
private void imagePDF_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{

    this.image_Transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X; 
    this.image_Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

    imageDeltaX = this.image_Transform.TranslateX;
    imageDeltaY = this.image_Transform.TranslateY;

    //update mark position
    
    foreach (var p in Points)
    {         
       Shapes[Points.IndexOf(p)].Margin = new Thickness(p.x + imageDeltaX, p.y + imageDeltaY, 0, 0);     
       Labels[Points.IndexOf(p)].Margin = new Thickness(p.x + imageDeltaX, p.y + imageDeltaY, 0, 0);     
    }

   }
```

I'm still a beginner to UWP and C# so my solution isn't probably the best. I am open to all sorts of improvements and advice.

I tried to do it with Canvas.Left / Canvas.Top but still with no success. It seems that marks "anchors" to an image, when I first drag the image. But I do not call any methods / code to do so.

Comment: Interesting problem.  Could you override your current image-movement code so the image and the annotations are re-rendered/moved in the same function?  Rather than moving the image, and then moving the annotations based on the properties of the image? Sounds like the image may have to stop moving in order to pass its location/variables back to the annotation movement code, hence the lag (just guessing).

Comment: Could you please post complete codes of that page(XAML and the code-behind codes) or share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: I nearly solved already.. Basic problem was in method that add Point of Interest to ground plan.. This method is perfectly ok. Maybe  it's not best solution how to move several ui elements on canvas but it works. So far mark doesn't teleport out of image.. but rather jumps to the right and down about 20px.. I hope I can solve it via canvas.. I will post solution ASAP

Comment: this link on zipped project on my OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvJbQLp7j9tJgchqrBycelI_4dheNw

Comment: Can anyone recommend me a good tutorial on canvases? If canvas is child of grid, does it take whole screen? I would like to understand how canvas behave..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Ok, this is final solution:

```
    private void imagePDF_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        tapPosition = e.GetPosition(sender as Image);

        var x = tapPosition.X;
        var y = tapPosition.Y;

        AddMarkToPosition(++countPOI, x, y);

    }

    private void AddMarkToPosition(int id, double x, double y)
    {

        Points.Add(new PointOfInterest(countPOI, x, y));

        DrawShape(x, y);
        DisplayLabel(x, y, id.ToString());    

    }

    private void DrawShape(double x, double y)
    {
        shape = new Ellipse
        {
            Width = 30,
            Height = 30,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
        };

        shape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x - 15 + imageDeltaX);
        shape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y - 15 + imageDeltaY);
        Shapes.Add(shape);
        canvasPDF.Children.Add(shape);
    }

    private void DisplayLabel(double x, double y, string s)
    {
        label = new TextBlock
        {
            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
            FontSize = 25,
            Text = s

        };

        label.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x - 8 + imageDeltaX);
        label.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y - 20 + imageDeltaY);
        Labels.Add(label);
        canvasPDF.Children.Add(label);
    }

    private bool IsOutOfBorders(double x, double y)
    {
        var b = true;
        if ((x > (imagePDF.ActualWidth - 30)) || (x < 0) || (y > imagePDF.ActualHeight) || (y < 0))
        {
            b = true;
        }
        else b = false;
        return b;
    }

    private void UpdatePOI()
    {
        foreach (var p in Points)
        {
            Shapes[Points.IndexOf(p)].SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, p.x + imageDeltaX - 15);
            Shapes[Points.IndexOf(p)].SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, p.y + imageDeltaY - 15);

            if (IsOutOfBorders(p.x + imageDeltaX, p.y + imageDeltaY)) Shapes[Points.IndexOf(p)].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            else Shapes[Points.IndexOf(p)].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            Labels[Points.IndexOf(p)].SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, p.x + imageDeltaX - 8);
            Labels[Points.IndexOf(p)].SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, p.y + imageDeltaY - 20);

            if (IsOutOfBorders(p.x + imageDeltaX, p.y + imageDeltaY)) Labels[Points.IndexOf(p)].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            else Labels[Points.IndexOf(p)].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
    }

    private void imagePDF_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.image_Transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        this.image_Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

        imageDeltaX = this.image_Transform.TranslateX;
        imageDeltaY = this.image_Transform.TranslateY;

        UpdatePOI();

    }
```